# proftpd, 530 Login Incorrect

Tags: login, ftp, proftpd

I'm trying to set up proftpd to run some tests (not production, lab tests) and would like it to accept users and root user.

According to the manual proftpd uses the system user list.

However all my attempts to log in as any user (root or not) return

```
530 Login incorrect
```

(Needless to say the credentials are in fact correct.)

Following tips I found on the web I've tried (in proftpd.conf):

1) Comment out

```
#User ftp
#Group nogroup
```

2) Add

```
UseFtpUsers off
```

to no avail.

Comment: What does [proftpd debug logging](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html) show, when you attempt to log in?  The reason that ProFTPD only ever shows "530 Login incorrect", despite the real underlying cause of the problem, is to prevent _leaking useful information to potential attackers_.  Unfortunately, while good for security, this is bad for debugging.  The server-side debug logging will provide more information about what might be going on.